# can not link examples from programming principles and practice using c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to compile and link the following source code below. When I initiate the build sequence in Visual Studio 2012, I get the following errors (few more related to the Graph_lib). I don't understand why the linking is failing all the code is available. I have verified the symbol definition and declarations.

```
Error   11  error LNK1120: 10 unresolved externals  C:\Microsoft_Press\C++\Debug\first_gui\Debug\first_gui.exe  first_gui
Error   4   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall Graph_lib::Shape::draw_lines(void)const " (?draw_lines@Shape@Graph_lib@@MBEXXZ)   C:\Microsoft_Press\C++\Debug\first_gui\first_gui\source.obj first_gui
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall Graph_lib::Window::draw(void)" (?draw@Window@Graph_lib@@MAEXXZ)   C:\Microsoft_Press\C++\Debug\first_gui\first_gui\source.obj first_gui
Error   6   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall
```

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
#include "Simple_window.h"
#include "Graph.h"

int main()
{
    using namespace Graph_lib;

    Point tl(100,100);

    Simple_window win(tl,600,400,"canvas");

    Polygon poly;

    poly.add(Point(300,200));
    poly.add(Point(350,100));
    poly.add(Point(400,200));

    poly.set_color(Color::red);

    win.attach(poly);
    win.wait_for_button();
}

1>------ Build started: Project: first_gui, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall Graph_lib::Window::draw(void)" (?draw@Window@Graph_lib@@MAEXXZ)
1>source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall Graph_lib::Shape::move(int,int)" (?move@Shape@Graph_lib@@UAEXHH@Z)
1>source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: __thiscall Graph_lib::Shape::Shape(void)" (??0Shape@Graph_lib@@IAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Graph_lib::Open_polyline::Open_polyline(void)" (??0Open_polyline@Graph_lib@@QAE@XZ)
1>source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall Graph_lib::Shape::draw_lines(void)const " (?draw_lines@Shape@Graph_lib@@MBEXXZ)
1>source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall Graph_lib::Open_polyline::draw_lines(void)const " (?draw_lines@Open_polyline@Graph_lib@@UBEXXZ)
1>source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall Graph_lib::Closed_polyline::draw_lines(void)const " (?draw_lines@Closed_polyline@Graph_lib@@UBEXXZ)
1>source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Graph_lib::Polygon::add(struct Point)" (?add@Polygon@Graph_lib@@QAEXUPoint@@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall Graph_lib::Polygon::draw_lines(void)const " (?draw_lines@Polygon@Graph_lib@@UBEXXZ)
1>source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Simple_window::Simple_window(struct Point,int,int,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (??0Simple_window@@QAE@UPoint@@HHABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall Simple_window::wait_for_button(void)" (?wait_for_button@Simple_window@@QAE_NXZ) referenced in function _main
1>C:\Microsoft_Press\C++\Debug\first_gui\Debug\first_gui.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 10 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Have all the relevant .cpp files been added to the project? If the code is in a .lib, was it added to the list of linker inputs?

Comment: @dif all the lib have been added to the input. The source and header files have been added to the project also.

Comment: The functions it's complaining about aren't supposed to be pure virtual by any chance, are they (and someone forgot the `=0`)?

Comment: Open the project properties dialog, then choose `Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General`, set the setting for `Suppress Startup Banner` to `No`. Now actual CL commands will show up in the output window, and you will be able to copy and paste them here demonstrate that you have indeed included all the needed files to the project.

Comment: @n.m. please update with the project properties set to your recommendation..

Comment: @dif I don't understand your question. I'm really new to C++ and was expecting the source from the authors code to just work. We haven't gone over the virtual keyword yet...

Comment: @d_blk It's probably not that; I was grasping at a straw.

Comment: I don't see any cl or link command there. I might have forgotten how exactly to make them appear. Unfortunately I don't have a Windows machine with me to verify. Please try to "rebuild all" and post the entire log.

Comment: @d_blk [This MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1a6b67c1-534c-4db7-9f3b-5ceb0feebc82/lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-errors-with-stroustrups-new-book-and-fltk?forum=Vsexpressvc) may or may not be of help.

Comment: @dlf thanks for the link. My question now is how do I add the .cpp file to the project?

Comment: @dlf added the .cpp and it builds now... Thank you very much... I have wrestled with this for three days now.

Comment: @d_blk Hence my original comment asking whether *all* relevant .cpp files were in the project. ;) But don't worry about it; it's a lot to take in all at once if you're just getting started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dlf posted an [MSDN link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1a6b67c1-534c-4db7-9f3b-5ceb0feebc82/lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-errors-with-stroustrups-new-book-and-fltk?forum=Vsexpressvc) that suggested to add the .cpp files to the project. I followed the instructions and I'm now able to build and link successfully.